# How to wrap php code inside a function?

Tags: php, function

Hi i need to wrap this code inside a function to use it later , i am php newbie any help please

```
$term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
$taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
$current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
$args = array( 'child_of' => $current_term->term_id, 'hide_empty'=>false);
$terms = get_terms( 'tagportifolio', $args);
$assoc = taxonomy_image_plugin_get_associations();

if (!empty($terms)):
?>

<?php foreach( $terms as $child ): ?>
<?php if(array_key_exists( $child->term_taxonomy_id, $assoc )){echo wp_get_attachment_image( $assoc[$child->term_taxonomy_id], array(), false, 'thumbnail'); }
?>
<a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $child->name, $taxonomyName );?>">
<?php echo $child->name; ?></a ><br/>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php else: ?>
```

Thanks

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php

Comment: This isn't how Stack Overflow works. [Try something](http://whathaveyoutried.com) first.

Comment: And FYI, you don't necessarily need `<?php` and `?>` on every single line of PHP code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might help, little format,and use variable to return entire html if needed to make it function,

```
<?php
function formatOutput()
{
    $term_slug = get_query_var( 'term' );
    $taxonomyName = get_query_var( 'taxonomy' );
    $current_term = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $taxonomyName );
    $args = array( 'child_of' => $current_term->term_id, 'hide_empty'=>false);
    $terms = get_terms( 'tagportifolio', $args);
    $assoc = taxonomy_image_plugin_get_associations();
    $output = '';
    if (!empty($terms))
    {
        foreach($terms as $child ) 
        {
            if(array_key_exists( $child->term_taxonomy_id, $assoc ))
            {
                $output .= wp_get_attachment_image( $assoc[$child->term_taxonomy_id], array(), false, 'thumbnail'); 
            }
            $output .= "<a href=get_term_link( $child->name, $taxonomyName ) >$child->name;</a >";  
        }
    }
    else
    {
        /* else code  : might be empty output*/
        $output .= '';
    } 
    return $output;
}
 ?>
```

Comment: then i can use echo formatOutput();

Comment: excatly.Hope this may show you some hints,further you can add arguments to your function and make it more better.

Comment: update : when i use add your function code in my function page , the { else} give me syntax error ??

Comment: corrected.extra : was there after else