# PHP SQL - Needs isolating as it affects the rest of the page

Tags: php, mysql, include, isolation

I'm aware that Mysql is not preffered for obvious reasons, but It's not my decision to continue using it.

```
<?php

if (!mysql_select_db('dobhost_databaseexamplename', $con)) {
    echo 'Could not select database';
    exit;
}

$sql = ("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE recid = '" .$page. "'");
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

if (!$result) {
    echo "DB Error, could not query the database\n";
    echo 'MySQL Error: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<title>Carpets - <?php echo $row['title'];?></title>
<meta name="description" content="<?php echo $row['descr'];?>" />
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $row['keywords'];?>" />
<?php
}

mysql_free_result($result);
?>
```

this code works fine as an include, its database connection is set up elsewhere but it all works fine, the only issue is that when i include it into the template header, it breaks all the php code below it - Is there any way to isolate my query and php echos so that they won't affect the content below?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you get any error messages? Or do you see simply no output from the php below? Also i would close the db connection if you dont need it anymore with the following command: mysql_close($con);

Comment: What are the obvious reasons in "Mysql is not preffered for obvious reasons"?

Comment: @ONOZ Security and the fact that it's deprecated and will be removed from PHP.

Comment: The html below the code outputs fine, but anything that involves php seems to be breaking, so I can see the HTML and styling but not HTML which would normally be outputted by a few includes - as the php isn't running - hope this made sense :)

And yes, JimL is correct! :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it in a function, you may be defining vars, which are are used later on in another script.

Also the loop might be a bad idea, you could end up with multiple title elements.

```
echo 'Could not select database';
exit;
```

This is bad too, just throw an exception like this: `throw new \Exception('Could not select database');`

```
<?php
function getMetaTags($pageId) {
    global $con;

    if (!mysql_select_db('dobhost_databaseexamplename', $con)) {
        throw \Exception('Error selecting db');
    }

    $sql = (sprintf("SELECT * FROM sections WHERE recid = %d", $pageId));
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $con);

    if (!$result) {
        throw new \Exception(mysql_error(), mysql_errno());
    }

    if(!$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        throw new \Exception(sprintf('Page with id %d not found', $pageId);
    }

    return sprintf('<title>Carpets - %s</title>
        <meta name="description" content="%s" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="%s" />', $row['title'], $row['descr'], $row['keywords']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! Although I'm not sure how to do that.
I'll give this a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11719362/how-to-wrap-php-code-inside-a-function - If that is what you're advising? :)

Comment: just call `echo getMetaTags(somePageId);` in your head

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help Fre Akus! - but that code seems to have syntax errors on line 17 & 24 and when I put it in the page, it seems to halt all of the output from occurring :( 

Also, I should have mentioned that $page is defined on each page(a selection of 1, 2 or 3). So my index includes:
$page = '1';

Thanks again! :)